# How can I check the type of the next element?

Tags: jquery

How can i check that element after id="id" is paragraph?

```
<div>
    <p id="id">one</p>
    <p>two</p>
</div>
```

I want something like this, but working.

```
if ($("#id").next() == $('p')){}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A chain of [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) and [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) methods would do it in a readable way:

```
if($('#id').next().is('p')) {
    // it's a paragraph
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use standard nodeName property

```
if ($("#id").next().get(0).nodeName == 'P')
```

get(0) construct returns the underlying DOM element of the JQuery object